# Carpeta contenedora del proyecto tiene color gris

Tags: git, github

Subiendo mi proyecto a un repositorio en **GitHub**, me he encontrado con el inconveniente de que sube todas las carpetas exepto una, la *www*, la cual contiene el proyecto.

[image: www]

Intento de todo pero no es posible que suba los archivos que contiene dicha carpeta.

Estoy realizando un proyecto utilizando **Ionic Framwork**, Windows 10 32 Bits.

Comment: Ejecuta `git status --ignored` y actualiza tu pregunta con el resultado. Seguramente lo estás ignorando desde la configuración global.

Comment: @toledano aparecio esto [git status --ignored](http://pastebin.com/2YjvEvPw)

Comment: Pues no se ve nada anormal en esa salida. ¿Es posible que sea una característica de programa que estás usando y no de git? Intenta agregarlos con la opción `--force`. Consulta el manual https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add

Comment: @toledano pues lo habia solucionado antes, haciendo un par de malabares

Answer (score 1):

Eso es un [sub-módulo](https://github.com/blog/2104-working-with-submodules) [EN]. Está en color gris porque por alguna razón está apuntando a una localidad que ya no existe. Otras razones pueden ser que el sub-módulo haya sido configurado incorrectamente o porque en algún momento inicializaste git dentro de esa carpeta y borraste el repo. Cuando el sub-modulo está funcionando correctamente el color del icon es verde. Puedes revisar el historial del repositorio para verificar en que momento del tiempo se perdió el enlace. Si puedes usar alguna herramienta gráfica como SourceTree o el cliente de Github pues mucho mejor.

Comment: El historia lo reviso en consola o en GitHub

Comment: Utiliza el método donde más cómodo te sientas. Usando la consola tienes más opciones pero hay veces que el GUI ayuda a encontrar más rápido lo que buscas.

Comment: gracias por el consejo